# Entity Framework 6 code-first migration - starting with the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializer

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have started an EF6 project to store measurement results from analytical instruments. Each instrument has a built-in PC with and it's own results database.

Initially, the database initializer CreateDatabaseIfNotExists was used. On database creation, it creates an entry in the __MigrationHistory table with a non-unique MigrationId entry (timestamp differs from instrument to instrument, e.g. 201706011336597_InitialCreate), the ContextKey if the fully qualified type of my derived DbContext.

After a while, it was decided to add more result data to the database... Furtunately, only three new tables are required. There are no changes in the existing tables.

For that, I wanted to use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer. But I have to support the following two scenarios:

1. Existing database with the non-unique MigrationId, that has to be migrated to the extended version with the three new tables.
2. No database, create the database with the the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer.

How can I do this?

I have created an initial migration using the add-migration PM console command from the initial DbContext. That works well with scenario 2 (no database exists). From that starting point I can update my DbContext and create a new migration with the three new tables.

But how to support scenario 1? The Up() method of the initial migration contains the table creation code, that is not nessessary, because the tables already exist. Is an empty migration (add-migration -IgnoreChanges) helpful, maybe with a later timestamp than the initial migration?

Note: I have no access from the PM console to the target database(s), only on my developer machine to a test database.

Thanks and best regards

Karsten

**Update:**
I have modified the created initial migration with the static flag *TablesAlreadyCreated*.

```
  public partial class InitialMigraCreate : DbMigration
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Set this field to true, if the tables are already created by the 
    /// CreateDatabaseIfNotExists database initializer. Then, the Up()
    /// and Down() methods do nothing, but the
    /// migration is added to the __MigrationHistory table.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool TablesAlreadyCreated = false;

    public override void Up()
    {
      if (TablesAlreadyCreated)
        return;

      // several CreateTable calls here
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void Down()
    {
      if (TablesAlreadyCreated)
        return;

      // several Drop... calls here
    }
  }
```

I have also implemented a new database initializer class as follows:

```
public class MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionEx<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()

{
    ...

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
      if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

      // check whether a first migration exists from the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists database initializer
      var firstConfig            = new ConfigurationAutoCreatedDatabase();
      firstConfig.TargetDatabase = _config.TargetDatabase;
      var firstMigrator          = new DbMigrator(firstConfig);
      var firstDbMigrations      = firstMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations();

      // create the default migrator with the current configuration
      var migrator = new DbMigrator(_config);

      if (1 == firstDbMigrations.Count(migra => migra.EndsWith("_InitialCreate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
      { // This database was created using the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists database initializer.
        // That's an indication whether it's an old database
        // Do the custom migration here!
        InitialMigraCreate.TablesAlreadyCreated = true;

        migrator.Update();
      }
      else
      { // do the default migration the database was created with this MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionEx initializer
        InitialMigraCreate.TablesAlreadyCreated = false;

        migrator.Update();
      }
    }
}
```

It checks, whether the initial migration entry is from the *CreateDatabaseIfNotExists* initializer and disables the table creation/drop calls in the Up()/Down() methods in that case. *ConfigurationAutoCreatedDatabase* is a manually created derived DbMigrationsConfiguration class:

```
internal sealed class ConfigurationAutoCreatedDatabase : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyNamespace.MyDbContext>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <c>ConfigurationAutoCreated</c> object (default constructor).
    /// </summary>
    public ConfigurationAutoCreatedDatabase()
    {
      this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled        = false;
      this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
      this.ContextKey                        = "MyNamespace.MyDbContext";
    }
}
```

So, it works for both scenarios. I hope that helps other guys with a similar problem. It would be interesting, if there is an out-of-the-box EF workflow for that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common scenario that EF handles nicely. The non-migration initializers (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, etc) should be used in very early development (when you don't care about the data except for stuff that is seeded).

Once you are switching to migrations you should generate a baseline migration that takes a snapshot of your current model as you indicate (`add-migration MyStartPoint -IgnoreChanges`). This adds a migration with no Up() code and stores the current state of your code first model so that when you change the model only those changes are reflected. You could accomplish the same thing by commenting out the items that exist from the Up() code.

Now when you run against an existing database, it will check __MigrationHistory to see which migrations have been applied. If the database does not exist, it will be created. See [here](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) and [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/ef/migrations-under-the-hood) for more info.

Not sure what you are talking about with the MigrationId. EF handles that automatically unless you change your namespace (there is a workaround for that as well).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tested the workflow once again and found out, that it is very important to specify the **-ContextTypeName** argument when enabling migrations using the PM console command **Enable-Migrations**. As a result, the `ContextKey` property of the generated `Configuration` class is initialized with the fully qualified name of our derived `DbContext`. Otherwise, the `ContextKey` property of the generated `Configuration` class is initialized with the fully qualified name of the generated `Configuration` class itself. And then, migrations don't work.

Comment: One way around that is to explicitly give a contextkey in the constructor. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx)

Comment: You're right, the explanations (see given link) clarify that. The **-ContextTypeName** argument, that I finally used, has a similar result, i.e. the right `ContextKey` property in the `DbMigrationsConfiguration`. The problem was, that the default behaviour of the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` class did not work with the previously used `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` class. Now it works... Thanks